# Oracle - Can't delete/replace whitespaces

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Given the following sample statement, I simply can't get rid of the leading and trailing white spaces no matter if using a combination of `RTRIM()` and `LTRIM()` or `REGEXP_REPLACE()`:

```
select 
 test_column
,length(test_column) len
,regexp_replace(test_column, '(^[[:blank:]]+)|([[:blank:]]+$)','') rxp
,length(regexp_replace(test_column, '(^[[:blank:]]+)|([[:blank:]]+$)','')) len_rxp --22 characters expected, but is 26 
,rtrim(ltrim(test_column)) rltrim
,length(rtrim(ltrim(test_column))) len_rltrim --22 characters expected, but is 26 
from(
     select '   ABCDEF Hijklmnopqr S32              ' test_column --22 characters without and 29 including whitespaces
     from dual);
```

What's the matter?

Comment: is there `[[:blank:]]` in oracle?

Comment: Yes, it captures whitespaces and tabs

Comment: try it with `^ +| +$` and see if it works

Comment: No, synonyms for whitespace like the whitespace itself or \s, the more common way to write it, lead to the same wrong result.

Comment: I get 22, as expected

Comment: Alleged whitespaces contained tabulators, solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
select regexp_replace(test_column, '^(\t|\s)*(.*)(\t|\s)*$', '\2')
from (
      select '   ABCDEF Hijklmnopqr S32              ' test_column
      from dual
     );
```

This should divide your string in 3 parts (leading, meaningful text, ending) and return only the second one, thus cutting away the trailing and ending sequences of spaces and tabs

Comment: Strange, when I do it I still have length=26. What results do you get, when executing the lenght commands I mentioned above?

Comment: Maybe you have some "strange" character; check if you have the same result with DUMP ( just edited the answer)

Comment: Bingo! I had some trailing tabs instead of whitespaces! How can I trim also those?

Comment: \t doesn't work in Oracle, CHR(9) is the equivalent. Now it works!